# The type seq<'a> is not compatible with the type Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-interactive

When using the following code in an fsx file I get the error `The type seq<'a> is not compatible with the type Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>`.

```
module ReadOnly =
    let private asList<'a> (en:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>) : System.Collections.Generic.IList<'a> = 
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>(en) :>  System.Collections.Generic.IList<'a>
    let private asReadOnly<'a> (en:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>) = 
        new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<'a>(asList(en))
    let ofSeq<'a> (ss: 'a seq) = asReadOnly<'a>(ss) // <-- ERROR IS HERE ON ARGUMENT 'ss'
```

When using the same code in a `netcoreapp2.1` console application all is fine.

My `paket.dependencies` contains the following:

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget NETStandard.Library
nuget canopy
```

and I load the following:

```
#r "packages/NETStandard.Library/build/netstandard2.0/ref/netstandard.dll"
#r "packages/Selenium.WebDriver/lib/netstandard2.0/WebDriver.dll"
#r "packages/canopy/lib/netstandard2.0/canopy.dll"
```

> Note: I included netstandard2.0 as I was having issues with not finding `Object`

Comment: I certainly was able to replicate your issue. It seems to be a problem of incompatible versions. Unfortunately, I cannot offer any solution except the obvious one: use netcoreapp2.1. What issues are you having with `Object`?

Comment: @AMieres `The type 'Object' is required here and is unavailable. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.`

Comment: What code would I need to replicate the `Object` issue?

Comment: @AMieres If you remove the reference to NetStandard here it shows up: https://gist.github.com/dburriss/cffa00d4b0c30c1ac4c93858c538f870#file-canopyhelpers-fsx

Comment: Did the solution/workaround work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a full answer, but this is what I have found out.
To recap:

1. with `NETStandard.Library` error `seq<'a> is not compatible` shows.
2. without `NETStandard.Library` the error `'Object' is required` shows

Yet, in option #2, in my tests the code actually runs when invoked with FSI. 
Which means the error is a library conflict in the Intellisense module.

In my tests the script runs also when using the option `--noframework` and referencing either of these two:

- `packages/FSharp.Core/lib/net45/FSharp.Core.dll`
- `packages/FSharp.Core/lib/netstandard1.6/FSharp.Core.dll`

... although only with version 4.3.4 but not with version 4.5.0

**EDIT**

A possible solution is adding an explicit reference to the local GAC `netstandard.dll`, like this:

```
#r @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\netstandard\v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\netstandard.dll"
```

That seems to solve the issue for Intellisense

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use `List<'T>`'s method `AsReadOnly()`?

```
let ofSeq<'a> (ss: 'a seq) = (ResizeArray ss).AsReadOnly()
// val ofSeq :
//   ss:seq<'a> -> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<'a>
```

Comment: That did allow me to circumvent the issue (up voted).  As far as I understand though I should be able to treat `'a seq` as `IEnumerable<'a>`. I am interested in why that is not working. As @AMieres it does seem to be incompatible versions.